# Substituting item to every occurance in a list

Tags: list, recursion, replace, lisp, common-lisp

I'm just beginning to learn Lisp. My problem is that I am trying to substitute an item every time it occurs in the list. I have to do this using recursion and without any loops. The function start out as `(subste x y L)`.

Examples would be:

```
(subste 7 t '(it is 7)) → (IT IS T)
(subste 7 nil '(7 is not to (7))) → (NIL IS not TO (NIL))
(subste 7 nil '(5 is not (22))) → (5 is not (22))
```

Here's what I have to far:

```
(defun subste (x y L)
  (cond ((null L) nil)
        ((not (= (car L) x))
         subste (x y (cdr L)))
        ((= (car L) x)
         (let L 'y))))
```

I have run this multiple times and tweaked it multiple times but have had no luck considering the fact the error messages give little information and only just starting to learn Lisp. Thanks.

Comment: How about the standard [**subst**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm)?

Comment: What you have so far (if any syntax errors are corrected) is recursive,  since substantial is calling itself.  Also,  you mention am unhelpful error message,  but you haven't shown us *any* error messages.  Also, please format your code as code blocks, not online code.

Comment: You are using a `let` as-if it was `setf`, but: the `let` would just be a binding and would be unwound as soon as you left it, and `setf` would mutate your input data which is probably not what you want to do. Also, `cond` clauses are tried in order: if one of your clause is `((not x) body)`  then obviously the following clauses can assume that the test failed, and so `x` is necessarily true in following tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SUBST`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm) already implements your desired behaviour. You just seem to want the old and new element to be in different order, so a simple wrapper would do:

```
(defun subste (x y l)
  (subst y x l))
```

If you want to implement it for your own, below is a simple version. Note the different branches:

- Recursing a tree always involves doing a recursive call on the first element of the tree and another one on the rest of the tree.
- Return `nil` at the end of the tree.
- If we found the element to be replaced, we change it.
- For any other atoms, we don't need to recurse, we just return the atom.

Here the example:

```
(defun subste (x y l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((eql l x) y)
        ((atom l) l)
        (T (cons (subste x y (first l))
                 (subste x y (rest l))))))
```

This version is not complete: You are not able to substitue elements, that are non-eql (like strings or sublists). You can add a test-function as an argument instead always using [`EQL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_eql.htm) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an implementation of **subst** is just a matter of walking the tree, checking whether nodes in the tree are the same as **old**, and replacing them with **new**.  In Common Lisp, functions like this usually take a **test** function to determine how the elements are compared (and often a **key** function, but I've omitted that here).  This leads to something like this:

```
(defun my-subst (old new tree &key (test 'eql))
  "Returns a completely fresh tree like TREE, but with occurrences of
OLD replaced by NEW.  The resulting tree shares no structure with the 
original TREE, except for leaves."
  (cond
    ;; If the current tree is the OLD element,
    ;; return the NEW element instead.
    ((funcall test old tree) new)
    ;; If the current tree is a cons cell,
    ;; call MY-SUBST recursively on both
    ;; the CAR and CDR of the tree, and
    ;; then CONS the results back together.
    ((consp tree) (cons (my-subst old new (car tree) :test test)
                        (my-subst old new (cdr tree) :test test)))
    ;; Otherwise, just return TREE.
    (t tree)))
```

```
(my-subst 'x 42 '(1 x 2 (3 x (4 (x) 5))))
;=> (1 42 2 (3 42 (4 (42) 5)))
```

Now, the tree returned by that implementation is always completely new.  That is, even if the **old** element *never* appeared in the tree, you'd still get a completely fresh tree back.  Depending on your use case, this could be kind of wasteful, memory-wise.  It might be beneficial to *check* whether the results of the recursive calls are the same as their inputs.  In that case, you can just return the input:

```
(defun my-subst (old new tree &key (test 'eql))
  "Returns a tree like TREE, but with occurrences of OLD
replaced by NEW.  The resulting tree may share structure
with TREE."
  (cond
    ((funcall test old tree) new)
    ((consp tree)
     (let ((new-car (my-subst old new (car tree) :test test))
           (new-cdr (my-subst old new (cdr tree) :test test)))
       (if (and (eq (car tree) new-car)
                (eq (cdr tree) new-cdr))
           tree
           (cons new-car new-cdr))))
    (t tree)))
```

```
(let* ((t1 '(1 x 2 (3 x (4 (x) 5))))
       (t2 (my-subst 'x 42 t1))
       (t3 (my-subst 'y 84 t1)))
  (list (eq t1 t2)
        (eq t1 t3)))

;=> (NIL T) ; t1 != t2, but t1 == t3
```

Which you'd want would depend on particular circumstances, but it'd good to be able to do both.